# How do you pass an argument to a PL/SQL block within a sql file called using START in sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a bash script running several sql files via sqlplus:

```
sqlplus $connectioninfo << end
start file1.sql
start file2.sql
start file3.sql $variable
quit
end
```

file3 has some PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(&1);

END;
/
```

But it just prints the literal `"&1"` instead of the value of `$variable`.  I have also tried the following in file3:

```
DEFINE var_a = &1;
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_a);

END;
/
```

and also the following:

```
DECLARE
  var_b VARCHAR2(64) := &1;

BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_b);

END;
/
```

and finally:

```
DEFINE var_a = &1;

DECLARE
  var_b VARCHAR2(64) := var_a;

BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_b);

END;
/
```

However, I am getting various errors or just the literal value '&1' for all of these.

Comment: just small correction

     ... >> end

should be rather

   ... << end

Comment: Thanks. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `SET DEFINE ON` to the start of your script `file3.sql`.

If `SET DEFINE` is `ON`, SQL*Plus will replace `&...` substitution parameters with their values.  If `SET DEFINE` is `OFF` (which it seems to be for you), SQL*Plus won't do this.

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed, my file1.sql had a `set define off` in it.