# Using ACCEPT, CASE to create CURSOR in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a script that will allow the user to select which CASE population to use from an `ACCEPT` when gathering student contact info.

```
PROMPT 'Select a popluation for emails'
PROMPT '1. Currently registered'
PROMPT '2. New Applicants'
PROMPT
ACCEPT cnt number PROMPT 'Selection: ';
...
CURSOR stu_lst IS  
CASE &cnt
    WHEN 1 THEN  -- Current registered students.
        select distinct SFRSTCA_PIDM pidm
        from   SFRSTCA
        where  SFRSTCA_TERM_CODE = '201403' and
               SFRSTCA_LEVL_CODE = '01' and
               SFRSTCA_RSTS_CODE = 'RE';
    WHEN 2 THEN  -- New applicants
        select app_pidm pidm
        from   app
        where  app_term = 'Fall 2014';
    ELSE
        -- Incorrect selection.
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Incorrect selection made.');
        exit;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass an argument to a PL/SQL block within a sql file called using START in sqlplus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558929/how-do-you-pass-an-argument-to-a-pl-sql-block-within-a-sql-file-called-using-sta)

Comment: Your extract isn't using the cursor - what will you do with it? Do you really want PL/SQL and a cursor, or are you trying to query the appropriate table and display the results, so plain SQL would do?

Comment: Have you ever written a SQL script only to have someone want the same data, just a different population of people. Then a month or two later, the original request comes back. Then someone else would like the same date, but they want a 3rd population. All the while you just make the little tweaks to the script because it's just easier to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with what I asked... I'm checking if you need PL/SQL because you're doing something with data from the cursor; or if you're just displaying it anyway.

Comment: I would like to be able to run the script, choose 1,2,3...???
depending on the choice entered it would run a specific SELECT script to create a population group (CURSOR list)

Comment: I would then LOOP through the CURSOR list to gather the needed data

Comment: BEGIN     
 -- LOOP THRU SELECTED STUDENT RECORDS     
 for rec IN stu_lst loop     
  h_pidm := rec.pidm;     
               ........    
END LOOP;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two queries return the same data type, you could use a union with a filter that checks the variable in each part; something like:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR stu_lst IS
    -- Current registered students.
    select distinct SFRSTCA_PIDM pidm
    from   SFRSTCA
    where  &cnt = 1 and
           SFRSTCA_TERM_CODE = '201403' and
           SFRSTCA_LEVL_CODE = '01' and
           SFRSTCA_RSTS_CODE = 'RE';
    UNION ALL
    -- New applicants
    select app_pidm
    from   app
    where  &cnt = 2 and
           app_term = 'Fall 2014';

  invalid_argument EXCEPTION;
  ...
BEGIN
  IF &cnt NOT IN (1, 2) THEN
    RAISE invalid_argument;
  END IF

  FOR rec IN stu_lst LOOP
    h_pidm := rec.pidm;
    ...
  END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN invalid_argument THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Incorrect selection made.');
END;
/
```

You could also declare a cursor variable and open that with the appropriate query, inside a case statement within the main body of the block. This sticks with your explicit cursor syntax though.