# how to do you assign an anonymous variable to a column in plsql?

Tags: plsql

I am trying to assign an input variable into pl/sql.

I want to query the database by letting the user input department_id and outputs the first name, last name, and salary. The salary is second highest salary in the table.

```
declare  
v_dept_id int; 

Begin
Select  emp1.first_name, emp1.last_name, emp1.salary,  emp1.department_id
From employees emp1
Where (1) = 
(select count(distinct(emp1.salary))
    From employees emp2
      Where emp2.salary > emp1.salary) ;
End;
```

clarification 
EDIT: I edited the code to include V_dept_id however it doesnt run 
declare
v_dept_id int;

```
Begin
Select  emp1.first_name, emp1.last_name, emp1.salary, emp1.department_id 
into v_dept_id
From employees emp1
Where ((1) = 
(select count(distinct(emp1.salary))
    From employees emp2
      Where emp2.salary > emp1.salary)) and v_dept_id = '&Enter_dept_id' ;
End;
```

error:

```
Error starting at line : 4 in command -
declare  
v_dept_id int; 

Begin
Select  emp1.first_name, emp1.last_name, emp1.salary, emp1.department_id 
into v_dept_id
From employees emp1
Where ((1) = 
(select count(distinct(emp1.salary))
    From employees emp2
      Where emp2.salary > emp1.salary)) and v_dept_id = '&Enter_dept_id' ;
End; 
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 16:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

**Edit2 based on answer below feedback with the error**
I don't know how to let the enter a number into the prompt correctly

```
declare  
v_dept_id number; 
v_fname varchar(50);
v_lname varchar(50);
v_salary NUMBER(8,2);

Begin
Select emp1.department_id, emp1.first_name, emp1.last_name, emp1.salary
into v_dept_id, v_fname, v_lname, v_salary
From employees emp1
Where ((1) = 
(select count(distinct(emp1.salary))
    From employees emp2
      Where emp2.salary > emp1.salary)) and v_dept_id = '&Enter_dept_id' ;
End;
```

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
declare  
v_dept_id number; 
v_fname varchar(50);
v_lname varchar(50);
v_salary NUMBER(8,2);

Begin
Select emp1.department_id, emp1.first_name, emp1.last_name, emp1.salary
into v_dept_id, v_fname, v_lname, v_salary
From employees emp1
Where ((1) = 
(select count(distinct(emp1.salary))
    From employees emp2
      Where emp2.salary > emp1.salary)) and v_dept_id = '&Enter_dept_id' ;
End;
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 8
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

Comment: where are you using v_dept_id ?
question is not clear .
in plsql if you are using select statement , you need to use INTO clause to assign values into some variable.

Comment: just added it! however it doesnt work

Comment: I want to create a PLSQL block, which takes as input, a department number, and outputs the first name and last name of the employee and the salary of the employee who has the 2nd highest salary within that department

Comment: What tool are you using to run your code?

Comment: I'm using SQL Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raj_Te has explained why your code will not compile.  But I don't much like your method of retrieving the second highest salary.  I guess your method works but it's not clear what that section of code is trying to achieve.

In the following code the DENSE_RANK function will return the salary ranking of each row.  Any rows that have the same salary will get the same rank :

```
SELECT
 emp.first_name
,emp.last_name
,emp.salary
,emp.department_id
FROM
 (SELECT
   emp1.first_name
  ,emp1.last_name
  ,emp1.salary
  ,emp1.department_id
  ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY emp1.department_id ORDER BY emp1.salary DESC)  dr
  FROM
   employees      emp1
  WHERE emp1.department_id = &dept_id
 )   emp
WHERE 1=1
AND emp.dr = 2
;
```

By stating emp.dr = 2 we are saying we want all rows where the salary is ranked second highest.

Comment: thanks it worked but I need to remove the emp1 in the first select statement so in the first select statement it would be `SELECT first_name, last_name, salary, department_id`

Comment: yes, indeed, my apologies.  The alias should have been emp - I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting 4 fields in a single variable. Thats why its givng not enough values. You must decalre either 4 variables or create a records with 4 columns and then capture the values.

```
Select  emp1.first_name, emp1.last_name, emp1.salary, emp1.department_id 
into v_dept_id  <--- trying to fetch 4 columns values to a single varibale.
```

You can decalre new variables of same datatype as of your selection and do it:

```
Select  emp1.first_name, emp1.last_name, emp1.salary, emp1.department_id 
into v_emp_first_nm,v_emp_last_nm ,v_emp_sal,v_dept_id
```

Comment: okay. what about taking a input let say the user wants to enter 90 into the prompt that shows up when you run the query? I havent quite figured that out yet. Also I modified it see above with the error again

Comment: this should solve your problem  ===   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558929/how-do-you-pass-an-argument-to-a-pl-sql-block-within-a-sql-file-called-using-sta                  Also look for the below link ==== http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-passing-parameters-procedure-function.htm

Comment: PL/SQL isn't interactive. Prompting for input is the the job of a client application such as SQL\*Plus, Perl or Java. If this will always be run from SQL\*Plus, look at [ACCEPT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm).